# Is it possible to release GPU allocated resources in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I know this question has been asked in a few different times [1](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2201), [2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1587) on GitHub. However, my question differs in a few key ways, so please don't close right away as a duplicate.

I'm training a number of different models in a loop, to compare their performance across a variety of time periods. It looks roughly like this:

```
for period in periods:
    train_df, test_df = utils.split_train_test(
        df,
        period.min_train,
        period.max_train,
        period.min_test,
        period.max_test
    )
    train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y = extract_features(train_df, test_df)
    model_2_mlp = models.train_2_layer_mlp(train_X, train_y, verbose=0)
    local_results['2_layer_mlp'] = model_perf.eval_keras(
        model_2_mlp,
        train_X,
        test_X,
        train_y,
        test_y
   )
    model_5_mlp = models.train_5_layer_mlp_with_dropout(train_X, train_y,
                        verbose=0)
    local_results['5_layer_mlp_dropout'] = model_perf.eval_keras(
        model_5_mlp,
        train_X,
        test_X,
        train_y,
        test_y
    )
    ...
    # save local_results to a file
```

After a few iterations of the loop, tensorflow throws an OOM error. However, no individual model exhausts the GPU. I can even restart the code at the offending time stamp and the models with train correctly. It's only after prolonged execution that I get this error.

Is there any way to force a GPU garbage collection?

Specific error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[28277,2000]
and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[{{node training_28/Adam/gradients/dense_93/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to R
unOptions for current allocation info.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `keras.backend.clear_session()` to remove all models from memory, you should use this at the end of each loop iteration.

Comment: Is it possible to delete only a selected model (not all models)?